# Get the date of the className or classID

Tags: php, functions

Is it possible to get the date of the class name or class ID?

I just used the following to get the date of the post, but there are image galleries and each image has a different upload date:

```
echo get_the_date( $postid );
```

I want to get the date of the image, not the post. If a user clicks the 2nd image, and the date is different from the 1st image, the date will automatically change.

My classname is `"img.attachment-shop_single.wp-post-image"`,
Twenty Ten theme.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
echo get_the_date( classname );
```

Comment: date it was uploaded or the date it was taken?

Comment: You are going to have to parse the class and run a query to get the post date. Are you certain there is no other way to do what you want? That is a lot of work for what seems like a minor effect. Maybe explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish in context instead of asking how to do some small piece of the task.